# Animate object off of screen with no lag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I've been using Animate.CSS and basic Jquery to animate elements on and off the screen. The issue is this has been creating a lot of lag due to a background slideshow occurring at the same time as the on screen animations. I've been looking into alternatives to help fix this issue.

I've read about using Opacity and TranslateZ etc to have elements come in and off of the page.

What would be the best way to change my code below to potentially lag less during animation?

```
 //Screen 7 Start 
//Highest Planned College
$( "#screen7" ).hide()

$(".buttonsQuestion7").click(function() {
$('#screen7').addClass('animated slideOutUp');
$('#screen7').fadeOut()
$( "#screen8" ).show()
$( "#screen8" ).addClass('animated slideInUp');


});
```

Comment: having many on-screen elements with partial opacity and RGBA colors will drop your perf like a lead balloon. don't add axtra opacity, use visibility:hidden or display:none, and dumb down the "see-through-ness"

Comment: Thank you! Let me give this a shot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had lag problems too with jQuery animations. The problem was lying in having several animations after one another like you have :

```
$('#screen7').fadeOut();
$( "#screen8" ).show();
```

What fixed it for me was to call the second animation in the callback of the first one like so:

```
$('#screen7').effect('fadeOut', {
    direction: 'left', 
    mode: 'hide', 
    duration: '300',
    complete: function(){

        $('#screen8').show();
    }
});
```

In this case i am using `.effect()` from jQuery UI but `.fadeOut()` has the same `complete` callback option

http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/

Hope that helps

Comment: Let me give this a shot!